# How to generate three different thumbnail after uploading video using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('change', function(event) {
          var file = event.target.files[0];
          var fileReader = new FileReader();
          if (file.type.match('image')) {
            fileReader.onload = function() {
              var img = document.createElement('img');
              img.src = fileReader.result;
              document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
            };
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
          } else {
            fileReader.onload = function() {
              var blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: file.type});
              var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              var video = document.createElement('video');
              var timeupdate = function() {
                if (snapImage()) {
                  video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
                  video.pause();
                }
              };
          video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            if (snapImage()) {
              video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
            }
          });
          var snapImage = function() {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var image = canvas.toDataURL();
            var success = image.length > 100000;
            if (success) {
              var img = document.createElement('img');
              img.src = image;
              document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
              URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
            return success;
          };
          video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
          video.preload = 'metadata';
          video.src = url;
          // Load video in Safari / IE11
          video.muted = true;
          video.playsInline = true;
          video.play();
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }
    });
```

```css
div {
  line-height: 200px;
}

img {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

@supports (object-fit: cover) {
  img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
 <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg.,.gif,.png,.mov,.mp4" />

<p><strong>Select a video or image file</strong><br /></p>

<div></div>
```

I am new to java script please help me out how to generate three different thumbnail. I am able to generate only one thumbnail, Please anyone help me out to solve.

I am giving my following code of java script and html

***Please help me out how to generate three different thumbnail***.I am able to generate only one thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

instead of using this thumbnail js can you just use the canvas to capture the image  when the video is played and you need multiple images then call that function which generates canvas images multiple times after the video is played.

see the example here  : -

```js
function capture(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
}
```

```html
<video id="video" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls></video><br/>
<button onclick="capture()">Capture</button> <br/><br/>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas> <br/><br/>
```

Comment: thanks, how will I generate only three thumbnail without clicking button?@vinayakkyadav

Answer (score 0):

Hey Pranjal i came up with a solution you can see it below hope it helps you :-

```js
        window.onload = function () {
            let video = document.getElementById('videoId');
            let canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
            let img = document.getElementById('imgId');
            let imgInt;
            video.addEventListener('play', function () {
                imgInt =   setInterval(function(){
                    draw(video, canvas, img);
               },1000);
            }, false);
            clearInterval(imgInt);
            
        };
        function draw(video, canvas, img) {
            
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            img.setAttribute('src', dataURL);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  
</head>
<body>
    <video id="videoId" autoplay loop controls>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>
    <img id="imgId" src=""/>
</body>

</html>
```